# date-fns not working on serverless edge function?

Tags: nuxt.js, vercel, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

In my Nuxt 3 project when I use date-fns it works fine (deployed on Vercel):

**server/api/datefns.ts**

```
    import { subDays } from "date-fns"

    export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
        const someDate = subDays(new Date(), 1);
    
        return {
            someDate,
        }
    })
```

But when I let it be deployed as a serverless edge function it throws an error:

```
TypeError: t is not a function
at (index.mjs:1:110837)
at (index.mjs:1:110877)
at (__nitro:middleware.js:1:17)
```

Did I miss something? I know Edge Workers have limited a API compared to Node but I tried to set up a simple worker function with date-fns and it works on Cloudflare Workers.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with how the bundling works.

- Issue from Nitro: https://github.com/unjs/nitro/issues/1889
- Issue from date-fns: https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/1781